# Extension of the series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ to complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

You can prove, without too much trouble, that :
$$\ln(1+x) = x- \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n}$$
This is true if $|x|<1$ and $x \in \Re$ but also if $x$ is a complex number. I know how to prove this with real numbers, but how can I extend this definition to the complex plane ? Can I simply say it works the same way, by replacing the real values with complex ones ? Or are there specific things one has to pay attention to ?

I have a start of university math level, by the way.

Comment: The series expansion only holds for $\lvert x \rvert < 1$ not for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: How do you define $\ln(z)$ when $z$ is a complex number?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I define the complex-logarithm as $ln(z) = w$ so that $e^w=z$

Comment: @BrockenDuck Note for example that $e^{0}=e^{2\pi i} =1$, so what is $\ln 1$ with your definition? Is it $0$ or $2\pi i$? $\ln$ will be a multivalued function and it is more natural to define it on a complex Riemann surface. The principal value of $\ln$ is defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ with the convention that $\ln 1=0$.

Comment: @Gary $z=re^{i\theta}$ then a logarithm of $z$ is $ln(r) + i(\theta + 2\pi k)$

Comment: @BrockenDuck A function, by definition, assigns precisely one value to each element in its domain. Your $\ln$ is therefore not a function.

Comment: @Gary The complex logarithm *is* a function, albeit a multi-valued one. That's not to say it's a *nice* function. The logarithm of a complex number depends on the $\arg$ function. If you start following a circle around the origin starting at a real number $r$, the $\arg$ function starts growing from zero until it nears $2 \pi$ when it is finishing a full turn. In consequence, the $\arg$ function cannot be continuous on any circle that surrounds the origin, and neither can the logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conditions for $z$ is from this book *Classical Algebra*, G. Paria, page 221:

The series holds true for complex quantity $z=x+iy$ with following conditions:

I. The modulus of $z$ is less than unity, or

II. The modulus of $z$ is equal to unity but the argument of $z$ is not equal to an odd multiple of $\pi$.

By definition we have:  $\operatorname{Ln}(1+z)=2n\pi i+\ln(1+z)$, it follows that:

$$\operatorname{Ln}(1+z)=2n\pi i+z-\frac{z^2}2 +\frac{z^3}3- \cdots,$$

where $n$ is zero or an integer (positive or negative).

Note that $\operatorname{Ln}(1+z)$ is not the same as $\ln(1+z)$ which is:

$$\ln(1+z)=z-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^3}3 - \cdots$$

and is called principal value of $\operatorname{Ln}(1+z)$ and results in when $n=0$.

Comment: How would one prove that ?

Comment: @BrockenDuck, see Complex logarithm in Wiki.